# How to find min & max screen height/width ratio for all available Android phones?

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like my app to display correctly on any Android device, regardless of screen size, screen density or ratio of screen height to width.  I want to support Android devices as old as API 8. I can create separate layouts for portrait, landscape and perhaps xlarge screens, but beyond that I don’t want to create different layouts for different densities or screen sizes.

I have read the Android guide on [supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html/). I try to follow those guidelines, for example,  for widgets I set their height and width to wrap_content or fill_parent, and I avoid using specific pixel measurements. For images, I provide alternative bitmap resources for different densities, or sometimes I use a specific size with density-independent pixels (dip), so the system will size it correctly on screen with different densities.

Over the past 2 years I’ve probably read that guide dozens of times.

I understand that I could define specific resources (e.g. layouts) for specific screen sizes and densities, but there are dozens or hundreds of phones I’d like to support, so that seems futile. I see table 3 in [that guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html/) shows some common dimensions for screens, but I want to make sure my app runs on nearly every phone.

It seems to me that what I need is to know is the narrowest screen (in dip) and the shortest screen. That is, I want to know the ratio of height versus width.

For example, in portrait orientation, perhaps I have a list of buttons or other widgets. I would really like to know which phone is shortest: has the largest ratio of width to height, so I can see if my layout is cut off at the bottom. Perhaps I also have 3 tabs: I would like to know the narrowest screen so I can make sure the tabs are not cut off on the right.

If I knew the minimum and max of h/w ratio for all the current Android phones, for portrait I could test on merely two Android Virtual Devices (or even just a custom screen in Eclipse).

I have taken to examining [Wikipedia’s list of Android devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices/), but someone must have a better way.

Comment: Not sure what the exact min/max are, but if you tested against 2:1 and 1:2, I think you'd be safe. Any devices outside that range would be exceedingly rare.

Comment: Thanks, that's not a bad heuristic, but I was wondering if anyone a way of figuring what Android devices were out there (parsing the Wikipeidia page or a spreadsheet of devices, etc.).

Comment: I think you should stop being such a control everything around you. Just follow the guidelines and believe that everything will work.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunatly I still haven't found that. I have this link: [List of displays by pixel density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density) but not all are Android devices. I know there are a couple of weird devices with square screen ratios (motorolas). But I would simply stick to [Google's screen sizes list](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#testing) and you should be safe for 99.9% of you users.

Edit1: [stats about screen sizes and densities](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Edit2: From my experience, I usually make 5 quick checks:

1. App on a HDPI phone with 16:9 ratio
2. App on a MDPI phone with 4:3 ratio
3. App on a XHDPI phone
4. App on a LDPI phone
5. App on a large screen tablet (usually MDPI)

I feel with those 5 cases I cover all screen densities (to check for image sizes in particular), most common screen ratios (4:3 & 16:9, to check all layout elements are accessible), and two most common screen sizes (phone & tablet).

Comment: Good to know about the list of displays by pixel density. And square screens! Oh my. But Google does not say what percentage of users is represented by their list of screen sizes - tho they must have that data!

Comment: Yep, was the Motorola FlipOut. I doubt it took a significant share of the market though :)

Comment: And you got some stats about screen sizes and densities (see edited answers)